# How to fix error when complice the makefile with mytee

Tags: c, unix, makefile, operating-system

When I finish the code (mytee.c) using getopt API to write implement a command in UNIX and use make test to test the file I got this message:

```
"make test
gcc -o mytee mytee.c
make test1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/programmer/proj1'
./mytee -v
usage: mytee [-av] _filename_
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/programmer/proj1'
make test2
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/programmer//proj1'
cat mytee.c | ./mytee mytee.fout > mytee.out
Expected argument after options
make[1]: *** [Makefile:32: test2] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/programmer/proj1'
make: *** [Makefile:21: test] Error 2"
```

when I run the test the follwing files will be created: mytee.fout mytee.out mytee random.bin

The makefile is like this:
[makefile][1]

When I make this command `diff mytee.fout mytee.c`, i got this message: 0a1,77. enter image description here. What I should do to fix this error in order to run properly?
My codes are here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<assert.h>


#define USAGE_MESSAGE "usage: mytee [-av] _filename_"

/* globals and externs go here */


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int ch ;
    int is_verbose = 0 ;
    int is_append = 0 ;
    char * mode_s = NULL ;
    char * filename ;
    FILE * f ;
    int nsecs =0;
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "va")) != -1) {
        switch(ch) {
        /*
         * modify or add to these case statements
         */
        case 'v':
            is_verbose = 1 ;
            break ;
        case 'a':
            mode_s= optarg;
            is_append = 1 ;
            break ;
        default:
                printf("%s\n", USAGE_MESSAGE) ;
                return 0 ;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind; 
    argv += optind;

    if (argc!=1) {
            printf("%s\n", USAGE_MESSAGE) ;
        return 0 ;
    }

    filename = argv[0] ;
    if (is_verbose) { 
        printf("%s:%d: openning file %s in mode %s\n",
                __FILE__, __LINE__, filename, mode_s) ;
    }
    f = fopen(filename,mode_s) ;
    assert(f) ;
    while (1) {
    
    while (ch = getchar()&&ch != EOF) {
        putchar(ch);
        ch = getchar();
    }
    printf("verbose=%d; append=%d; optind=%d\n", is_verbose, is_append, optind);
      printf("name argument = %s\n", argv[optind]);
    break;
    }
     if (optind >= argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
     return 0; }
```

and the makefile is right here

```
make mytee

test: mytee
        make test1
        make test2
        make clean
        @echo "*** ${GREEN}PASSED the test ${NC}***"

mytee: mytee.c
        gcc -o mytee mytee.c

test1: mytee
        ./mytee -v

test2: mytee
        cat mytee.c | ./mytee mytee.fout > mytee.out
        diff mytee.fout mytee.c
        diff mytee.c mytee.out

test3: mytee
        dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=4096 of=random.bin
        cat random.bin | ./mytee mytee.fout > mytee.out
        diff random.bin mytee.fout
        diff random.bin mytee.out


mytest: mytee
        @echo "student adds tests, for instance,"
        @echo "* mytee called without argument,"
        @echo "* mytee called with -a option"

clean:
        -rm mytee.fout mytee.out mytee random.bin
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear, and your code is too complicated. In `test1`, you call `./mytee -v`, but the code expects an additional parameter, `filename`. What is your intention?

Comment: That's in the usage message : #define USAGE_MESSAGE "usage: mytee [-av] _filename_"

Answer (score 0):

The list of arguments includes the name of the program. The first argument to the program is in `argv[1]`.

So if you call

```
./mytee
```

you will get

```
argc:    1
argv[0]: "./mytee"
```

The command producing the error is

```
./mytee mytee.fout
```

and you will get

```
argc:    2
argv[0]: "./mytee"
argv[1]: "mytee.fout"
```

But you are checking `argc` against 1, not 2.

---

*Note: You can find out such things a) by reading the documentation, or b) by writing simple tests like this:*

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%d: \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```